# how to replace a letter in string with Haskell

Tags: haskell, duplicates

i have to make Haskell function called markDups that processes a string, replacing all repeated occurrences of a character with the underscore, "_", character.

here is my code i did so far.

```
makeBar :: Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
makeBar c  (x:xs) | c == x = '_':makeBar c xs --turn into a "_"
                  | otherwise = x:makeBar c xs--ignore and move on
```

when I run this, here is my output with error message
[image]

output should be like this

[image]

what should I do?

Comment: You should add a case for empty lists.  Give instructions for what  `makeBar` should do when it's passed something like `makeBar 'o' []`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
import Data.Set
main = putStrLn (markDups "hello world" empty)


markDups :: [Char] -> Set Char -> [Char]
markDups [] set = []
markDups (x:rest) set
 | member x set = '_':(markDups rest set)
 | otherwise    = x:(markDups rest (insert x set))
```